# JavaScript array to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Write  a function called "convertObjectToList" which converts an object literal into an array of arrays, like this:
Argument:

```
{
  name: 'Holly',
  age: 35,
  role: 'producer'
}
```

Return value:

```
[['name', 'Holly'], ['age', 35], ['role', 'producer']]
```

Note that your function should be able to handle ANY object like this, not just the exact sample provided above.

E.g., it should also be able to handle this, or any other object containing simple key-value pairs.

```
{
  species: 'canine',
  name: 'Bowser',
  weight: 45
}
```

---

I tried to get the size of an object and then turn it into an array by assigning array[number] a value and a key at a time in a for loop, can you tell me how to do this, when I call the sizex(obj1); I get 3, but when I call convertObjectToList(obj1); I get empty array: [].

I took JS around 10 days ago, and some tasks are still kinda confusing as I'm in a process of learning. Any help is welcome.

Here is the code I have for now:

```
var names = [];
var values = [];

var sizex = function(obj) {
    var num = 0;
    var lol;
    for (lol in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(lol)) num++;
    }
    return num;
};

function convertObjectToList(obj) {
    // your code here



    for (j = 0; j < sizex; j++) {

        for (var name in obj) {
            names[j] = name;

            values[j] = obj[name];
        }
    }
    return names.concat(values);
}


var obj1 = {
    name: 'Holly',
    age: 35,
    role: 'producer'
}

sizex(obj1);
convertObjectToList(obj1);
```

Thank you guys, both codes work, second code is more simple but the website gave me an error saying "converts_some_other_data = false" and first code worked fully. Thanks again.

Comment: You can use var sizex = Object.keys(obj).length Instead your function;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and `map()`

```js
var data = { name: 'Holly', age: 35, role: 'producer' }

function toArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(e => [e, obj[e]])
}

console.log(toArray(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function in ES2017 that does exactly that: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Converting_an_Object_to_a_Map).

```
const convertObjectToList = Object.entries;

convertObjectToList( {
  name: 'Holly',
  age: 35,
  role: 'producer'
} );

// [['name', 'Holly'], ['age', 35], ['role', 'producer']]
```

It works in the version of node.js I have (7.2.0) without any flags or anything. It probably works in earlier versions too, but I'm not sure how far back.